# When validating a form with querySelectorAll - how to select the appropriate span to output the error

Tags: javascript

I am adding event listeners to `input` fields with `querySelectorAll` and I am wondering how to display an error messagge in the appropriate span, when a form "error" occurs.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203891/use-queryselectorall-to-select-second-element-of-the-list) post, which looks promising, but I don't know if it's do-able with my current aproach.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(input){
    input.addEventListener("blur", function (){
        if(input.validity.valueMissing){
            //select appropriate span
        }
    })
})
```

```
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required placeholder="Please enter your Surname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" />
</br>
<span class="error" id="e_surname"></span>
</br>
```

*Not related* - Additionally I would like to display different error messagges for e-mail/telephone/etc input fields... I don't know if I can roll all of that in one "function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `span` is a sibling of your `input`, you can scan forward to it:

```
let span = input.nextSiblingelement;
while (span && !span.classList.contains("error")) {
    span = span.nextSiblingElement;
}
if (span) {
    span.textContent = /*...*/;
}
```

Ideally, though, if you can change the markup, I'd make them children of the same container element instead:

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required placeholder="Please enter your Surname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" />
    <br/><!-- If this can't be done with CSS for whatever reason -->
    <span class="error" id="e_surname"></span>
</div>
```

Then you could find it with `closest` and `querySelector`, which might give you more flexibility in terms of changing your HTML without changing your JavaScript:

```js
const span = input.closest("div").querySelector(".error");
if (span) {
    span.textContent = /*...*/;
}
```

You *could* do it with `id`s, since you're using `id`s on those elements:

```
const span = document.getElementById("e_" + input.id);
if (span) {
    span.textContent = /*...*/;
}
```

...but if you can do it structurally, it saves you having to manage lots of `id` values.

Comment: Quick question. I switched from innerHTML to append/remove textNode since it was pointed out to me that innerHTML is not safe. Is textContent "safe"?

Comment: @WeAreDoomed - I assume you're speaking in terms of XSS attacks and such. Yes, `textContent` is safe in that regard, where `innerHTML` isn't if what you're assigning to it is user-derived content.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `.error` span `id` is prefixed with `"e_"` followed by the field name, you can just look it up using:

```js
document.querySelector(`#e_${input.getAttribute('name')}`)
```

I would also wrap your pattern with `^` (line start) and `$` (line end): `^[A-Za-z]{2,15}$`, because without you could allow names longer that 15 characters.

If you wan this to be implicit, you can add them in the `RegExp` constructor call:

```js
pattern: input =>
  (pattern =>
    pattern ? new RegExp(`^{pattern}$`).test(input.value) : true)
  (input.getAttribute('pattern'))
```

### Example

```js
const VALIDATION_RULES = {
  required: input =>
    (required =>
      required || (required && input.value.length > 0))
    (input.hasAttribute('required')),
  pattern: input =>
    (pattern =>
      pattern ? new RegExp(pattern).test(input.value) : true)
    (input.getAttribute('pattern'))
};

const validateRules = (input, rules) =>
  rules.reduce((acc, rule) => acc && VALIDATION_RULES[rule](input), true);

const onInputBlur = e => {
  const
    input = e.target,
    valid = validateRules(input, [ 'required', 'pattern' ]);
  document.querySelector(`#e_${input.getAttribute('name')}`)
    .classList.toggle('show', !valid);
}

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input =>
  input.addEventListener('blur', onInputBlur));
```

```css
.error { display: none; color: red; font-size: smaller; }
.error.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required
  placeholder="Please enter your Surname"
  pattern="^[A-Za-z]{2,15}$" />
<br/>
<span class="error" id="e_surname">Please enter a valid value</span>
<br/>
```

A better way to handle this, would be to group the error with the input. This way you can go up to the wrapper and back down to the error, for any given input.

You could even create a rule validation class that has default rules and accepts new ones. You would have a `detect` and `isValid` function for each rule.

```js
class RuleValidator {
  constructor(rules) {
    this.rules = {  ...RuleValidator.defaultRules, ...rules };
  }
  validate (input) {
    return Object.values(this.rules)
      .filter(({ detect }) => detect(input))
      .reduce((acc, { isValid }) => acc && isValid(input), true);
  } 
}

RuleValidator.defaultRules = {
  required: {
    detect: input => input.hasAttribute('required'),
    isValid: input => input.value.length > 0
  },
  pattern: {
    detect: input => input.hasAttribute('pattern'),
    isValid: input => new RegExp(input.getAttribute('pattern')).test(input.value)
  }
};

const
  validator = new RuleValidator(),
  onInputBlur = e => {
    const
      input = e.target,
      field = input.closest('.field'),
      valid = validator.validate(input);
    field.querySelector('.error').classList.toggle('show', !valid);
  };

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input =>
  input.addEventListener('blur', onInputBlur));
```

```css
.field > label { font-weight: bold; }
.field > .error { display: none; color: red; font-size: smaller; }
.field > .error.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label>Surname</label>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" required
    placeholder="Please enter your Surname"
    pattern="^[A-Za-z]{2,15}$" />
  <span class="error" id="e_surname">Please enter a valid value</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I don't fully understand the code you have provided it may be a good starting point to look into some of these things.